# Facebook photo uplaod is not working with electron + nodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, reactjs, electron

```
Application Stack : Facebook Photo Upload + Graph API v.2.8 + Electron + NodeJS + ReactJS
```

I am trying to implement Facebook photo sharing in my application. I got Facebook Login working manually due to some electron JS issues with reactJS.

All other Facebook endpoints are working like : `/me/feed`, `/me/post` etc

But `/me/photos` is not working as expected.

Its uploading an already hosted image on internet with http url but when i try to add local file into the request it didn't work.

I have used `nodeJS` Library => `facebook-node-sdk` but got no luck.

With `facebook-node-sdk` it updated user feed with messages and other requests but image upload didn't work. It gives me this error :

```
TypeError: self._form.on is not a function
```

And I figured out the issue here : [Node Facebook Issue](https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk/issues/67)
I used this code with `facebook-node-sdk` :

```
    FB.setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    domtoimage.toBlob(node, { height: node.scrollHeight }).then(function (imageData) {
        FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
          access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
          url:  'https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png', // This one works fine
          // This one below shows error : 'TypeError: self._form.on is not a function'
          url:  fs.createReadStream(`${SHARE_IMAGE_PATH}shareFile.png`),
          // I tried also with Blob Object as :
          url:  imageData,
          caption: 'Share',
          debug: 'all'
        }, function (res) {
         if(!res || res.error) {
           console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
           return;
        }
        console.log('Post Id: ' + res.post_id);
      });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```

---

### Then I tried with https nodejs request like below :

```
domtoimage.toPng(node, { height: node.scrollHeight }).then(function (imageData) {
      let photoBuffer = new Buffer(imageData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), 'base64');
      shareImagePathExists().then(exists => exists ? exists : createShareImagePath()).then(() => {
        log.info('Saving Screenshot to ' + SHARE_IMAGE_PATH);
        fs.writeFile(`${SHARE_IMAGE_PATH}shareFile.png`, photoBuffer);
      }).then(() => {
        let formData = {
          access_token: accessToken,
          url:  'https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png', // This one works fine
          // This one below returns 'requires upload file error'
          url:  fs.createReadStream(`${SHARE_IMAGE_PATH}shareFile.png`),
          caption: 'Share',
          debug: 'all'
        };
        console.log(formData);
        let postData = querystring.stringify(formData);
        let post = {
          host: 'graph.facebook.com',
          path: '/me/photos',
          method: 'POST',
          headers:
          {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': postData.length,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        };
        let req = https.request(post, function (response) {
          let result = '';
          response.on('data', function (data) {
            result = result + data;
          });
          response.on('end', function () {
            if (response && response.statusMessage === 'OK') {
              dispatch(facebookActivityShareComplete());
              dialog.showMessageBox({
                title: 'Share Success',
                message: 'Activity Shared to Facebook.',
                buttons: []
              });
              console.log('Response Success: ', response);
            }
          });
          response.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('REQUEST ERROR: ' + err.message);
          });
          console.log('Response recieved: ', response);
        });
        dispatch(facebookActivitySharing());
        req.write(postData);
        req.end();
      });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```

Above Code returns `requires upload file error` each time. I am using `facebook graph API v2.8` I tried many solution like using `request` npm package for nodeJS but nothing seems to be working with uploading image from `local file path` or `base64Data` or `Blob` Object.

Any kind of assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Error :
`Uncaught TypeError: self._form.on is not a function request.js:1134.`

It looks like Electron Browser don't support the .on('error') call for `request` node package. And we can't use `node-facebook-sdk` [here](https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk/issues/67) as it uses `request` at the back to send data requests. So, I tried some other packages and got it working with `needle` [here](https://github.com/tomas/needle). Then I did some more research to do a `multipart/form` request to upload image to facebook. And end up doing it like :

```
domtoimage.toBlob(node, { height: node.scrollHeight }).then(function (imageData) {
      let form = new FormData();
      form.append('filename',  'source');
      form.append('file', imageData);
      form.append('caption', CAPTION);
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN);
      request.send(form);
      request.onload = () => {
        if (request.status !== 200) {
          console.log('Response : ', request.responseText);
        }
      };
    }).catch(function (error) {
      log.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```

And It worked fine.